# SignalR Hub throws NRE

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, signalr, signalr-hub

I have an issue with null reference exception and can't understand why does it happen. Here is my hub

```
public class UserHub : Hub
    {
        private static List<Connection> Users = new List<Connection>();

        public override async Task OnConnected()
        {
            string id = Context.ConnectionId;
            string userName = Context.User.Identity.Name;

            if (Users == null)
                Users = new List<Connection>();

            if (!Users.ToArray().Any(_ => _.UserName == userName))
                Clients.AllExcept(Context.ConnectionId).onNewUserConnected(id, userName);

            if (!Users.ToArray().Any(x => x.ConnectionId == Context.ConnectionId))
                Users.Add(new Connection { ConnectionId = id, UserName = userName });

            Clients.Caller.onConnected(id, userName, Users.DistinctBy(_ => _.UserName).ToList());

            await base.OnConnected();
        }


        public override async Task OnReconnected()
        {
            string id = Context.ConnectionId;
            string userName = Context.User.Identity.Name;

            if (Users == null)
                Users = new List<Connection>();

            if (!Users.Any(_ => _.UserName == userName))
                Clients.AllExcept(Context.ConnectionId).onNewUserConnected(id, userName);

            if (!Users.Any(x => x.ConnectionId == id))
                Users.Add(new Connection { ConnectionId = id, UserName = userName });

            Clients.Caller.onConnected(id, userName, Users.DistinctBy(_ => _.UserName).ToList());

            await base.OnReconnected();
        }

        public override async Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
        {
            if (Users == null)
                Users = new List<Connection>();

            var item = Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ConnectionId == Context.ConnectionId);
            if (item != null)
                Users.Remove(item);


            Clients.All.onUserDisconnected(Context.ConnectionId, item.UserName);

            await base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
        }
    }
```

the issue occures in onConnected method, in this line:

```
if (!Users.ToArray().Any(_ => _.UserName == userName))
```

I've tried to add check for null above but it doesn't work. What's wrong? The issue occures in random times.

Stack trace:

```
at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at App.Web.Hubs.UserHub.<OnConnected>d__1.MoveNext() in E:\Company\App\App\Presentation\App.Web\Hubs\UserHub.cs:line 49
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
...
```

Comment: So what exactly **is** null? Users? An entry in the list? Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: I believe it's ok If entry in the list is null and smth wrong with Users. I've added stacktrace to initial message

Comment: Well, seems like the `_` is null in your list.

Comment: How did it happen, I'm not adding null values into Users array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is not thread safe so you can see all sorts of issues when accessing the `Users` list. Multiple connections can start or close at the same time and they're all accessing the static `Users` property. Consider using a concurrent data structure or a lock when accessing the list.

Comment: Or, don't use a static field.

Comment: Static fields are fine. The Hub is a transient class, so if you want to store state between clients and requests you either need a static field, or a service that stores the state for you (which also needs to be thread safe).

Comment: That's what I was getting at: much better to use a service, especially considering that DI is omnipresent in .NET nowadays. Of course, as you said, you still need a thread-safe data structure within that service.